# Unique for every user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ip

I am trying to add a like functionality to comments/conversations. I plan to add a boolean quantity in the database. This quality has a relation with a user. However I am not able to find a unique property in a particular user using which the user can be identified. Eg. I store public ip addresses of users but many users can have same public ip connected to the same network. My devices connected to wlan have the same ip. I want that a user cannot like a conversation more than once and so I am using boolean. Either true or false. What property of a user can I get access to in `req.body` so that each user is distinguished from other devices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a unique id for your users ?

Comment: Nope, I am required not to register users.

Comment: Ok. What are the information that you have on the users ? Maybe you can create a hash with the user agent and the IP address, and have something close to unique

Comment: I'm afraid ,but I think that could not be the best possible solution. I do have the user IP address (ipv4). I use this address to block certain users on my website. However, many devices could use the same public ip address, devices connected to the same network. If I use ip to get about adding this functionality, a network can like just once. I want this functionality to be added to the device rather than the network. What could be unique in every single device/user?